# Internet Explorer thinks it's Safari when running GWT apps

Tags: gwt

My GWT app doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8. For some reason it thinks it's a safari browser. If I force it run as ie8 it works but I get a warning saying it's safari.
Any idea what happened? My coworker is able to run the same app in IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason that can be, is if you have [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) installed.

Follow this [link](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/chrome-frame-faq#TOC-How-can-I-uninstall-Google-Chrome-F) for uninstall instructions.